# "login failed for myuser" when changeing the connection string settings to use sql user

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

I've setting up an asp.net core application that use Identity.
With the default connectionstring, it works fine.
If I change the connection string (in the appsettings.json file), forcing it to use a specifed user to access the database, it doesn't work.

The working settings are:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {"DBContextConnection": "Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Persist Security Info=True;"
```

}

Inspecting sql server in the working scenario (using activity monitor), user DOMAIN\myuser logged in successfully.

Changing the connection string settings as below (where myuser is a sql user, not a windows user), it doesn't work:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {"DBContextConnection": "Server=myserver; Database=mydb;User   ID=myuser;Password=mypassword"}
```

With this configuration I get the following: login failed for myuser

The stranger things is that it doesn't work also using DOMAIN\myuser

PS: I can login with both user using sql server management studio and execute query on the aspnet tables.

Comment: It actually is not about netcore or identity. You need to check user credentials for your database. Can you check if you can connect to your database with myuser credentials via management studio(or any other db editor)?

Comment: I forgot to say that I can login with both user using sql server management studio and execute query on the aspnet tables.

Comment: Please post solutions as an answer,  not in the question itself. See [why we remove “solved” from question titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311829).

Comment: The extra spaces between User and Id on the second connection string failed when I tested it, Can you try User ID with only one space?